# Store nested entity in Hbase and read it as rows in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase

My requirement is to write a nested entity(Array of POJO objects) from Java to Hbase and to read them as individual records in Hive.

(i,e) while writing from Java, its just a single string(Array). But from hive, the array represents the table as a whole. So the hive should have the individual elements of the array as individual records in it.

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Thanks,
GK

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should take a look to [Hive UDTF functions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-Built-inTable-GeneratingFunctions(UDTF)) like `explode`, depending on what you store and what you need to retrieve they may work for you but be noticed they have some important limitations:

> - No other expressions are allowed in SELECT `SELECT pageid, explode(adid_list) AS myCol...` is not supported
> - UDTF's can't be nested `SELECT explode(explode(adid_list)) AS myCol...` is not supported
> - GROUP BY / CLUSTER BY / DISTRIBUTE BY / SORT BY is not supported `SELECT explode(adid_list) AS myCol ... GROUP BY myCol` is not
>     supported

---

If standard UDTFs don't fit your case and you're in the mood, you can also do this:

1. Store each item of your array as a json string in a different column: i0, i1, i2 ... iN
2. [Write your own UDTF function](https://blogs.oracle.com/datawarehousing/entry/three_little_hive_udfs_part1) to process each row columns and emit 1 row per column.

---

IMHO, I'll just write one row per element of the array, appending to the rowkey the index of each array item, it will be faster when processing the data and you'll have a lot less headaches. You shouldn't worry about writing billions of rows if that's the case.